# How to root HTC Desire (Froyo 2.2) without putting in a custom ROM (flashing)?

Tags: htc-desire, rooting

for research purposes I'd need to root a HTC Desire phone without flashing it. I did it already on the HTC Hero, where it was quite simple.

Basically all I would need is to get r/w access to the /system/app folder for copying my custom apk file there. Obviously this needs root access.

Is there a way to easily root the Desire without the need to completely flash and place a custom ROM on it?

Some details about the phone:

- OS: Froyo 2.2
- Software number: 2.12.110.4
- Kernel version: 2.6.32.15

Thx for your help

Comment: See also: [How to root a HTC Desire running official Android 2.3?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17587/16575)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unrevoked 3 will root the HTC Desire without replacing the ROM, however it does reflash the recovery ROM: http://unrevoked.com/#desire

Comment: What does it mean it does reflash the recovery ROM?

Comment: Does Unrevoked 3 wipe the phone during the process? Will I require to install and use a backup app before I do the rooting?

Comment: @Alastair Yes, apparently it wipes the phone and installs Android v2.1-update1

Comment: @Matt I got root access on my Desire, however also after successfully mounting /system with rw, when I copy an apk there, I get "cannot create /system/app/myapp.apk: not enough memory". Do you happen to know a possible solution to this? Booting in recovery and copying there just works fine...

Comment: Sorry Juri, I'm stumped.  Post it as a new question and hopefully some of the more savvy users will be able to help.

Comment: @Matt nop, posted it here (as future reference for others): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/copy-apk-file-to-system-app-getting-not-enough-space

Comment: HTC phones have an extra protection for /system