# Why do I get "not enough space" when I copy an APK file to /system/app?

Tags: htc-desire, internal-storage, file-system, file-transfer, apk

I recently rooted my HTC Desire Bravo because I needed read/write access to `/system/app` in order to be able to copy an APK file there.

I [wrote here on stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-to-root-htc-desire-froyo-2-2-without-putting-a-custom-rom-flashing) on the best solution to root the Desire and got pointed to Unrevoked. Everything worked fine and typing "su" in the adb shell gives me nice root access.

I re-mounted /system like

```
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

That worked. However, trying to copy my APK file using `adb push MyApp.apk /system/app/` didn't work and gave me a "permission denied". Alternatively I therefore pushed the app to /sdcard first and wanted to do a

```
cat /sdcard/MyApp.apk > /system/app/MyApp.apk
```

That approach has worked just perfectly on my rooted HTC Hero, on the Desire however it gives me

> "Cannot create /system/app/MyApp.apk:
>   not enough memory"

Does anyone have a clue on what could be the problem here?  How can I push my app to the system folder so that it installs properly?

Answer (score 3):

HTC phones have an *extra* protection of the /system folder, rooting them is not enough to get write access there.

You need to turn off that protection. This is most easily done with the [Revolutionary tool](http://revolutionary.io/). Follow the instructions closely on the site.

Comment: The Revolutionary tool link is dead.

Comment: Oh man, @Raptor, my HTC is dead too, almost. Haven't done anything with it in more than a year.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if *cat* is the best option to copy a file. Why don't you try the *cp* command. I can imagine that *cat* reads the whole file into memory an if it's too big this error happens.

Comment: `cp` won't work within adb shell

Comment: are you sure? i recently moved a file to the system/lib folder using clockwordmod recovery and "mv", EDIT: just realized, you didn't specify if you where using recovery...you have to boot into recovery because the system part of the flash is copy protected (called s-on). only in the recovery mode you can write to it

Comment: yep, just recognized it myself and it works now. Should be a way to boot it with "s-off", right?

Comment: Yes, but it involves flashing a custom/hacked bootloader which can brick your phone.

Comment: If you're rooted you *should* be able to replace "cp" with "busybox cp", you can download Busybox if you don't have it already.

Comment: @Juri You might have seen this already, but if not then Google Alpha Rev for the s-off method for Desire, which will give you write access to the system partition within the ROM etc...

Answer (score 1):

Hameno is right. Although adb will appear to work if the phone is booted normally, it actually won't. You need to boot the phone into clockworkmod, then fire up adb, mount /system yourself (something like mount -o rw /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system), and muck around with the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the app [Root Explorer](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-speedsoftware-rootexplorer-Fiq.aspx).  It's the best file manager in my opinion and you can easily remount /system and copy files with it.

[image]