# How do I disable Fast boot without the Power option in Settings?

Tags: htc-desire, fastboot

I went over some of the old forum posts about this issue and there seems to be a lot of confusion about this. I am planning to root my HTC Desire (GSM) which at the moment is running original UI/ROM and everything on Android 2.2 FroYo.

One of the root guides said that I should disable Fastboot by going to Settings and then Power. But I don't have that option. And apparently I am not the only one.

So what's this all about? And how do you disable something like that when the option is not there? Can this be done from HBoot menu?...

Comment: *Note to self: Fastboot and "Fast boot" ain't the same thing. [Fastboot](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) is a protocol used by Android to diagnose and flash new firmware images, while "fast boot" is just a term used to describe a new kind of power state that enables you to faster start up the phone.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on Android 2.3.3 with root, S-OFF and custom ROM (SuperNova) and I can confirm now that the option to toggle between Fast boot enabled and Fast boot disabled is available. Now, to properly answer my own original question, this is how you would disable it on HTC Desire.

1. Press Menu button.
2. Tap Settings.
3. Tap Applications.
4. Remove the checkmark from the option "Fast boot" to disable it.
5. Press Home button.

Screenshot:

[image: fast boot option on htc desire]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the they didn't make fastboot an option until Gingerbread. It should be off by default so I wouldn't worry about that step. You can check to see if it's on by turning your phone completely off and then turning it on to see how long it takes to boot up. If it only takes 10-15 second fastboot may be enabled.

Also, here is a painless way to root your HTC Desire that doesn't require changing fastboot: [How to root HTC Desire (Froyo 2.2) without putting in a custom ROM (flashing)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/how-to-root-htc-desire-froyo-2-2-without-putting-in-a-custom-rom-flashing)

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking following this guide: http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/HTC_Desire and I am currently setting up the SDK, ADB, driver, etc. But the actual installation involves Revolutionary for S-OFF and ClockworkMod for recovery. This will give me the special options in HBoot that allow me to flash another ROM, right? But so... this doesn't allow me to get root access only, without changing the ROM?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. I believe unrevoked gives you root and s-off but it's not clear on their site. You could follow that method and if it doesn't give you s-off you could use revolutionary to get it. Eitherway you choose if you don't have the option to turn fast boot off its probably not enabled.

Comment: Fastboot is more like a hibernation power state of Android devices, right? Well it takes me 45 seconds just to get past the HTC logo screen, and 90 seconds in total to load up the system and all the apps and widgets. So it's safe to conclude then that this device is not in fastboot mode, right? So I will not need to disable fastboot anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Fast boot in Android 2.3.5 on HTC desire is found under

1. Menu
2. Settings
3. Power

Fast boot option is found in Power

Comment: You're on 2.3.5? On what ROM?